# Convert .bin to .png or .jpg on a server

Tags: php, iphone, image, png, jpeg

I am uploading images from an iPhone to my server. The code that I'm using converts the image to binaries (with a .bin extension). I would like to transform these into .png or .jpg so I can then reference them back on my app when making a UIImage.

If this can be done in php, great. Otherwise I'm open to all solutions.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

[Here is a link to the file.](http://ericbrotto.com/test/upload/sample@2x.bin)

**EDIT 2**

Fixed link :)

Comment: What's a binary in this context?

Comment: What is this .bin extension? Is your code encoding your images in a base64 string so that they can be safely transported inside an HTTP packet? If so you should just decode them in your server and store them with the correct extension.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure I really understand myself. Basically I have a file on my server that has .bin extension, but it is an image.

Comment: Yes, actually it does seem to be base64 encoded. How does one decode this?

Comment: Can you open that file in the Microsoft Paint Brush for example? Is it a text file or a binary file? Can you post the first few lines of it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are using PHP right? If so I think that you can use this [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php):

`string base64_decode ( string $data [, bool $strict = false ] )`

to decode a base 64 string.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, but how do I: `a)` get the string from the .bin file and `b)` take the converted data and make a `.jpg` out of it? Also, please see my EDIT 1. Thanks!

Comment: Well to get the string from the .bin file I think that you can just open it and put all of its contents inside a string. I really don't know PHP so I can't help you there... To make the converted data into a jpeg, just decode the base 64 string and write it to file (please note that you need to write the actual byte array to the file, if you write a string containg your binary data, the jpeg will not work). Also the link you posted on EDIT 1 is not working...

Comment: Hi, I've looked at your file and it is not encoded in base 64, it is actually a valid png file. I've renamed its extension from .bin to .png and could open it without any problems.

Comment: Dude! You rooooooooooooooooooooooooooooock!!!!!!!!!! Thank you, thank you, thank you :)